# Can I display the listfragment first then load the list later?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment and an associated adapter.

The adapter implements the AbsListView.OnScrollListener.  In short, when the OnScroll() method is called, the adapter call the API service and load the list.

The problem is when user clicks on the button that opens the ListFragment, there's a brief delay before the user can see the fragment.

I'd like to change the design, so that the ListFragment will show IMMEDIATELY after the button is clicked with the message "Loading."  Does anyone have any recommendation?  Thanks!

Comment: That's basically what `ListFragment` already does by default, if you're not using a custom `View`, and you don't set the `Adapter` until you have data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a view for show when loading, such as show a ProgressBar.
First, you need to extends a Custom SimpleCursorAdapter with LoaderManager

```
public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

1.Add global view

```
  View startview;
```

2.Inside the Constructor build the progress bar and set the LoaderManager's callback

```
        //Build the progressBar

 ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this.mContext);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    //Set startview for future call  and add to root view

        startview = progressBar; 
        root.addView(startview);

   //Set Interface the LoaderManager will call to report 
        context.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
```

3. Override onLoadFinished to remove the progressbar view after finish.

```
     @Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader,Cursor data) {
       if (startview!=null) {
           if (startview.getParent()!=null) {
                ((ViewGroup)startview.getParent()).removeView(startview);
                                         }
                         }
        }
```

4. Set use the custom Cursor Adapter

*Global*

```
   protected CustomSimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
```

*Override onCreate for set use the custom adaptor*

```
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  ...

            mAdapter = new CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout,  c, from,
                to, flags);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                  ...
}
```